# system.in.read miss execution

Tags: java, switch-statement

Why after the first loop, the switch will execute twice before it stop to wait for my input? Is there any char left in the standard input? How can I fix the issue?

```
while(true)
{
int choice = System.in.read();
switch(choice)
{
   case '1':
       break;
   default:
       break;
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you do some investigation and actually print out the characters you're receiving?  My guess would be you're hitting enter, which on a Windows system is two characters: `0x0D` and `0x0A`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[InputStream#read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) only reads a single `byte` and will not consume the newline character (will be 2 characters, `LF` and `CR` on Windows platforms), passing it through to the next `read`. This `read` will now *not* block having received input and the flow will fall through to your `default` case.

You could use a `BufferedReader` instead and read a full line:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
...
int choice = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

Comment: I am on linux, do you mean the System.in.read will consume LF in linux?

Comment: Yes, indeed, you can check this by looking up `System.getProperty("line.separator")`

Comment: Thanks! I am still little confused. I saw the document said inputstream.read(which is system.in.read) read a byte, while inputStreamReader.read read a character. So is that mean in linux, a char in represented by 1 byte? but when I type a char it consist of 'a/n'? Is there a function in java like sizeof to see the actual size of the content you get

Comment: No, as it's an ASCII character, it's still only one `byte`. As Java is line buffered, the linefeed automatically follows. By reading the line & parsing the `LF` is dropped. To get the size using `readLine`, use `length` on the `String` returned.

Answer (score 2):

By taking the time to read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) you would have noticed that this method takes in a single byte of data. If you hit Enter after you type in the data, then that will add another byte to the `System.in` stream, meaning the Switch statement has more data to work with.. You should use a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to read streams like this.

**Example**

```
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
  // Create a scanner object that reads the System.in stream.
  int choice = s.nextInt();
  // Accept the next int from the scanner.
  switch(choice)
  {
    // Insert selection logic here.
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you again print choice somewhere, probably you will get 10 and 13.

- '10' is LF (line feed control char).
- '13' is CR (carriage return control char).

This is why the switch is executing twice.

And the better way of taking input already have been shown by Reimeus, Chris Cooney.

Answer (score 0):

This is an `Infinite Loop`. It will just keep taking the input.

You should be using a `Scanner` to get your input, than `System.in.read()`, like this:-

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true)
    {
        int choice = s.nextInt();
        if(choice == 1){
            break;
         }
    }
s.close();
```

Comment: You should avoid creating the scanner inside the loop since it is AutoCloseable and closes the input stream after the first iteration

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Break to Labeled Statement** in this case. for more information http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue110.html

**Here is workign code:**

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Switch {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        exitWhile: {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("type>");
                int choice = System.in.read();

                switch (choice) {
                case '1':
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Default");
                    break exitWhile;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```