# Java do-while loop skipping console input

Tags: java, do-while, system.in

```
class Noob1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) 
        throws java.io.IOException{

        char ch, answer;
        answer = 'g';

        do {
            System.out.println("Guess from A-L:");
            ch = (char) System.in.read();
                if(ch == answer){
                    System.out.println("Congratz!");
            } else System.out.println("Try again!");
        } while (ch != answer);
    }
}
```

The output is this:

```
Guess from A-L:
a
Try again!
Guess from A-L:
Try again!  // this is where intuitively it should ask for input again
Guess from A-L:
Try again!
Guess from A-L:
g           //  input is skipped a few times
Congratz!
```

I cannot figure out why, I'm reading a book for beginners and everything should've been covered, what am I missing?

Adding the code below at the end of the loop confirms that it is being looped but the input is somehow skipped.

```
i++;
System.out.println(i);
```

So I got it working using this:

```
import java.io.*;

class Noob1 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.io.IOException
    {
        char ch, answer;
        String tmp;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        answer = 'g';

            do 
            {
                System.out.println("Guess character followed by ENTER:");
                tmp = bufferedReader.readLine();
                ch = tmp.charAt(0); // only first char is considered
                if (ch == answer) 
                    System.out.println("Gratz! the answer was: " + ch + "!");
                else 
                    System.out.println("Nope, try again..");
            } while (ch != answer);
    }
}
```

Is the formatting still terrible?

Comment: It's useful to get in the habit of using consistent indentation and bracing right from the beginning. The code in the question could use some cleanup.

Comment: @Tunaki: The OP isn't using `Scanner`. But there may well still be an earlier version of this question using `System.in` directly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You are correct... silly me. Thanks for pointing this out. This would be more appropriate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239265/whats-wrong-with-for-loop or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296637/system-in-read-miss-execution

Comment: @Tunaki: Excellent finds, I used the first one.

Answer (score 3):

`read` only reads a single character, but when answering, you're typing more than one character: You're typing `a` *followed by a newline*, because console input doesn't get sent to the stream until you press Enter. That newline sits there in the stream waiting to be read by the next `read`, which is why it doesn't wait for you to type something again.

You may want to wrap `System.in` in a `BufferedReader` and use [`BufferedReader#readLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) and handle the fact you get a string instead of one character, or alternately after getting your character, call `read` repeatedly until you get the newline. I'd opt for `bufferedReader`.

Comment: Ah, that was briefly mentioned in somewhere.
Why does it loop through 3 times though? Doesn't a newline have a single value or why does it take up 3 buffer "spaces"?

How would I use bufferedReader in this example?

Comment: @naike: On some OS's (such as Windows), Enter = `\r\n`, which is two characters (carriage return [char 13] and newline [char 10]). Re `BufferedReader`, look through the JavaDoc and give it a go, again being aware of the fact you'll get a string instead of a char. If you run into trouble after spending some time on it, post a new question with your `BufferedReader` code.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared some things up, I'll give it a go.

Comment: Got it working, see first post. Thanks.

Comment: @naike: Updating a question like that isn't really something you should do on SO. Side note: There's no reason whatsoever to recreate your `BufferedReader` on each loop.

Comment: Ok, thanks, thought someone else might have the same problem. I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 1):

You are entering 2 characters at once - the character itself and a '\n' new line character. Replace your implementation of reading the character with this :

```
Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
char x = s.next().charAt(0);
```

charAt makes sure only first character is extracted.